# Make checked or unchecked from jquery in Angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, checkbox

If checkbox is checked then after reloading checkbox should be checked , If unchecked then should be unchecked. 
**Using in directive controller.**

```js
var checkboxValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || {},
    $checkboxes = $("#checkbox-container :checkbox");

$checkboxes.on("change", function(){
  $checkboxes.each(function(){
    checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
  });
  
  localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify(checkboxValues));
});

// On page load
$.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
  $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkbox-container">
  <div>
    <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="option1">
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Above code I took from this https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-persist-checkbox-checked-state-after-page-reload/

Above code is working fine. I am also using the Anguglar js. When I using in ng-model then value   `$("#" + key).prop('checked', value);` is not make checked checkbox in html page.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="option1" ng-model="mycheckbox" data-ng-change="call()" />
```

**Javascript controller:**

```
$scope.call=function(){
console.log("inside controller");
}
```

So in this case JQuery is not able to make true(checked) and false(unchecked) in html page. But if I don't use ng-model then It will works.

Comment: Use ng-model and don't mix jquery with angular. For more info on how to do it without jquery https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Comment: If your are updating anything outside angular code then you might have to  use scope.apply to run a digest cycle.Try to avoid using Jquery inside angular .

Answer (score 0):

Please try as per below code. Due to CORS problem localstorage not working so i commented out code for localstorage. Please refer below code.

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
    .controller('myController',['$scope','$window',function($scope,$window){
        $scope.checkboxValues=['true','false','true','false','true'];
         //localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues",JSON.stringify($scope.checkboxValues));
        //$scope.checkboxValues = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || [];

        $scope.changeCheckBoxVal=function(val,index){
            $scope.checkboxValues[index] = true;
            //localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues",JSON.stringify($scope.checkboxValues));
        }
    }  
])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myController">
            <div data-ng-repeat="chkBoxVal in checkboxValues track by $index">
                <input type="checkBox" ng-model="chkBoxVal" data-ng-change="changeCheckBoxVal(chkBoxVal,$index)"/>
            </div>
        </div>
 
    </body>
</html>
```